# Thrown objects scope

Tags: c++, exception

I was wondering if thrown objects obey the same scope rules in c++ as everything else. Here is an example.

```
try{
  Error err;
  err.num = 10;
  err.str = "This will be thrown."
  throw err;
}
catch(Error e){
  cout << "Error num is: " << e.num << " error string is: " << e.str << endl;
}
```

Does that work or does the fact that `err` was created in the `try` block stop it from being used in the catch block?

Comment: Yes, that works.  You throw "err", the catch block handles "e"; everything you initialized in "err" will be present in "e".

Comment: You're throwing a *copy*...

Comment: As far I know, the scope of in try declared variables ends at the execution of finally block (That is, after the catch). But I'm not sure

Comment: @Manu343726: No, the `try` block defines a scope, just like any other block. `err` is only in scope there, not in any associated handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering if thrown objects obey the same scope rules in c++ as everything else.

The thrown object itself doesn't have a *scope*, since scopes only apply to names and it doesn't have a name. It has a slightly special *lifetime*: it is constructed somewhere by the `throw` statement, and then destroyed once the exception has been handled. In this case, the thrown object is a copy of `err`. Also, since you catch by value, the caught object `e` is a copy of the thrown object, not the object itself.

> Does that work or does the fact that `err` was created in the try block stop it from being used in the catch block?

It "works" in that you can access `e` (a copy of `err`) in the `catch` block. You can't access `err` itself, since that has gone out of scope and been destroyed when the program left the `try` block; but the copy is still intact until you leave the `catch` block.

Comment: This is not a 'scope', this is a *lifetime.* Scopes are delimited by {} and nothing else. There is nothing special about the scope of thrown objects,

Comment: @EJP: The object itself doesn't have a scope at all since it doesn't have a name; so the only sensible answer is to describe its lifetime, and the scope of any copies or references to it. But thanks for the feedback; I'll fix the slightly sloppy language of my answer in a minute.

Comment: @EJP: I believe my terminology matches the C++ standard's now. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works.

You throw "err", the catch block handles "e"; everything you initialized in "err" will be present in "e".

You can absolutely "catch" any exception you "throw" in your "try" block.

'Hope that helps.

Comment: Without the definition of the `Error` class, you can't be sure that everything initialized in `err` will be present in `e`.